# Merge Two Text Files by a TimeStamp

Tags: c#

I have two plain text files I need to merge sorted by the **timeStamp** from one of the columns in the files.

**sample_A.txt**

```
05:37:58 01:00    0   0     |05:32:00|93328|5352|            |Description 1
05:43:58 01:00    0   0     |05:49:40|99256|5357|            |Description 2
05:44:58 00:30    0   0     |05:50:40|99301|5358|            |Description 3
```

**sample_B.txt**

```
04:58:11 00:02    0   0     |04:58:55|58787|0335|            |Description A
04:58:12 01:01    0   0     |04:59:00|57701|0336|            |Description B
06:09:37 01:00    0   0     |06:10:00|58181|0348|            |Description C
```

**output_File.txt** (this is what the file should look like after the merge)

```
04:58:11 00:02    0   0     |04:58:55|58787|0335|            |Description A
04:58:12 01:01    0   0     |04:59:00|57701|0336|            |Description B
05:37:58 01:00    0   0     |05:32:00|93328|5352|            |Description 1
05:43:58 01:00    0   0     |05:49:40|99256|5357|            |Description 2
05:44:58 00:30    0   0     |05:50:40|99301|5358|            |Description 3
06:09:37 01:00    0   0     |06:10:00|58181|0348|            |Description C
```

The time stamp is the first 8 columns, for example:
On file sample_A.txt:

```
05:37:58
05:43:58
05:44:58
```

This is the code I have, but it only appends the file in the same line using a delimiter, can I please get some help?

Thanks.

```
string[] files = new string[] { @"c:\temp\sample_A.txt", @"c:\temp\sample_B.txt" };
var hash = new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, bool>>();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    string[] fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    foreach (string line in fileContents)
    {
        string[] a = line.Split('|');
        if (!hash.Keys.Contains(a[0]))
            hash[a[0]] = new Dictionary<string, bool>();
        hash[a[0]][a[1]] = true;
    }
}
foreach (var key in hash.Keys)
    Console.WriteLine(key + "," + string.Join(",", hash[key].Keys.ToArray()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you can simplify.  do you need any kind of uniqueness here?

if not, you don't need all the hashmap/etc stuff at all, you could just read all the files and merge them into one big list, then sort that and output the sorted version?

```
string[] files = new string[] { @"c:\temp\sample_A.txt", @"c:\temp\sample_B.txt" };
var merged = new List<string>();
foreach (var file in files)
{
    string[] fileContents = File.ReadAllLines(file);
    Collections.addAll(merged, fileContents);
}

Collections.sort(merged);
foreach (string line in merged)
{
    Console.WriteLine(line);
}
```

if you need to only compare the first 8 chars of the timestamp, you can create+pass a custom comparator to the sort method?

if you need uniqueness of times, once the list is sorted, you can look at the last item and current (or current and next) and skip writing an item if the timestamps are the same.